# how to scan multiple lines without print statement

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
'''
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayIntegers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.print("#ofints: ");          
    String[] arrayStrings = new String [sc.nextInt()];  
    sc.nextLine(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayStrings.length; i++)   
    {  
        arrayStrings[i] = sc.nextLine();  
    }  
'''
```

-How can this be done with using hasNext() method (breaks if space is entered) so there is no need for user prompt statement.
so e.g.:

1

2

3

Instead of:

#ofints: 3

1

2

3

Comment: Use LineReader to read line by line and then apply the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hasNext() method checks if the Scanner has another token in its input. A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which matches whitespace by default.

Check this (stop on enter "exit"):

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String inputStr;

while (sc.hasNext()) {
    inputStr = sc.next();
    if (inputStr.equals("exit")) break;
    System.out.println(inputStr);
}
```

P.S. The hasNextLine() method checks to see if there's another line in the input of the Scanner object, no matter if the line is blank or not.